# How to properly create JSON arrays from two database table using Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django. I am trying to display database records from two tables in the following JSON:

```
[
{"id":"1","title":"post title 1","content":"post content 1.","totalrating":"4"},
{"id":"2","title":"post title 2.","content":"post content 2","totalrating":"1"},
{"id":"3","title":"post title 3","content":"post content 3","totalrating":"2"}
]
```

In Django I run this code below. I can successfully get all the posts records in json but without total rating.

**models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " " + self.content

class Rating(models.Model):
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    postid = models.IntegerField()
    tpy = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid + " " + self.postid
```

**view.py**

```
def read(request):
    response_data = [
    {'title': post.title, 'content': post.content} 
    for post in Posts.objects.all()]
    jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
    return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

**My Problem:**

My issue is getting the record of rating count based on postid. I know I can do something like this Eg.

```
rate = Rating.objects.filter(postid=1,userid=5).count()
```

Finally I tried  the following code below

```
def read(request):
    response_data = [
    {'id': post.id, 'title': post.title, 'content': post.content, 'total_rating': rate} 
    for post in Posts.objects.all()
    rate = Rating.objects.filter(postid=post.id,userid=5).count()
]
    jsondata = json.dumps(response_data)
    return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

it displays error **rate invalid syntax**. How can I get the database records as shown in JSON above?

In PHP I can easily get it with the code below

```
$response_arr = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM crud_posts";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$postid = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];

        // Count post total by id
        $pc_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntPost FROM crud_rating WHERE postid=".$postid;
        $pc_result = mysqli_query($con,$pc_query);
        $pc_row = mysqli_fetch_array($pc_result);
        $total_pc = $pc_row['cntPost'];

  }
$response_arr[] = array("id" => $postid, "title" => $title, "content" => $content, "totalrating" => $total_rate);
    }

    echo json_encode($response_arr);
```

Comment: In your `read()` function, I think your ending `]` of the list comprehension needs to be moved to right after `Posts.objects.all()`.

Comment: Hi Nofiinator,  if I tried that am getting error of variable rate referenced before assignment in an enclosing scope as per this 'total_rating': rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax isn't valid Python. But the way to do this is not by individually calculating the rating for each post, but to ask the database to do it for you; that would have made your PHP more efficient in the first place.

First, you need to change your Rating model to use actual foreign keys rather than integers:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, you can use `annotate()` to calculate the rating, and the `values()` method to get a dictionary:

```
from django.db.models import Count
data = Posts.objects.filter(rating__user_id=5).annotate(
    total_rating=Count('rating')
).values('id', 'title', 'content', 'total_rating')
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your response. I have implemented your solution but just having
this error

user =models.Foreignkey('auth.User')

-init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete